# Bomb in C# missing reference

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Error:

> Assets\Bomb.cs(43,43): error CS1061: 'Collider2D' does not contain a definition for 'AddComponentCircleAll' and no accessible extension method 'AddComponentCircleAll' accepting a first argument of type 'Collider2D' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

PointEffector2D explosionComponent;

```
   CircleCollider2D circleCollider;

   [SerializeField] private float AddTorqueAmountInDegrees;

   private float explosionRadius;

   void Start() {
       circleCollider = GetComponent<CircleCollider2D>();

       explosionComponent = GetComponent<PointEffector2D>();
       explosionComponent.enabled = false;

       explosionRadius = circleCollider.radius;
   }

   private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) {

     if (other.gameObject.name == "Player1")
         explosionComponent.enabled = true;

     Collider2D[] colliders = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(transform.position, explosionRadius);

     for (int i = 0; i< colliders.Length; i++)
     {
         Rigidbody2D rigid = colliders[i].AddComponentCircleAll<Rigidbody2D>();
         // The Error is supposed to be here ^

         rigid.AddTorque(AddTorqueAmountInDegrees *Mathf.Deg2Rad * rigid.inertia);
    }
 }
```

I know that I need to reference something on that line, but I don't how  (yeah I am new to C#).

Comment: Literally zero results on Google for "AddComponentCircleAll" - Are you sure you have the right thing?

Comment: That method doesn't exists, are you using a custom library that gives you extensions methods?

Answer (score 1):

The method you are calling `AddComponentCircleAll<RigidBody2D>` does not exist. I believe you want to change it to `AddComponent<RigidBody2D>` but more clarity on what you are trying to accomplish with that line would be helpful.

Comment: Yeah you are right Ive changed it to AddComponent, but the problem remains.

Comment: Assets\Bomb.cs(43,43): error CS1061: 'Collider2D' does not contain a definition for 'AddComponent' and no accessible extension method 'AddComponent' accepting a first argument of type 'Collider2D' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: No. Colliders don’t have that method. Game objects do